# php - how to parse an xml and show only the row where there is a particular value?

Tags: php, xml

I have an xml which is similar to this:

```
<xml>
<products name="product_list">
<product id="1" name="product_1">Soap</product>
<product id="2" name="product 3">Shampoo</product>
<product id="3" name="product_3">Sponge</product>
</products>
</xml>
```

I'm trying to import it via php (using simplexml) but I would like show only one row where the id match another variable I've set.

Something like :

```
echo product where product['id'] = $variable
```

But I have no idea how to do that.

Comment: You have to show what you have tried

Comment: helpful? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8105480/simplexml-get-value-where-attribute-is-variable

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get the title and complete class value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25348936/how-do-i-get-the-title-and-complete-class-value)

Comment: Use [xpath](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php)

Comment: Thanks so much!!!! i've solved it with the xpath solution in the answer trainoasis linked .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
<?php

$xml = simplexml_load_string('<xml>
<products name="product_list">
<product id="1" name="product_1">Soap</product>
<product id="2" name="product 3">Shampoo</product>
<product id="3" name="product_3">Sponge</product>
</products>
</xml>');

$variable = 2;

foreach ($xml->products->product as $row) {
  if ((int)$row->attributes()->id === $variable) {
    echo ((string)$row);
  } // if
} // foreach
```

It will show all products with id of 2...